# SWIFT: Using data defined in a UITableViewController in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm pulling data from Parse to display the number of user votes for a list of user generated song names -

[image]

[image]

As shown above, the number of items in each 'userVotes' array is counted and displayed to the left of the 'Vote' button.

Here is my code for the TableViewController -

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class MusicPlaylistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var usernames = [String]()
var songs = [String]()
var voters = Array<Array<String>>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    let query = PFQuery(className:"PlaylistData")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                self.usernames.removeAll()
                self.songs.removeAll()
                self.voters.removeAll()

                for object in objects {

                    let username = object["username"] as? String
                    self.usernames.append(username!)

                    let track = object["song"] as? String
                    self.songs.append(track!)

                    let title = object["userVotes"]!
                    self.voters.append(title as! Array<String>)
                    print("Array: \(self.voters)")

                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return usernames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTrack", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TrackTableViewCell

    //cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row]

    var voteCount: Int = voters[indexPath.row].count
    var voteCountString = String(voteCount)
    cell.votes.text = voteCountString

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



}


}
```

I have a custom UITableViewCell as shown below. I'm trying to increase or decrease the vote count depending on if the vote button if toggled on or off.  My issue is that I cannot seem to access the 'voter' array or the 'voteCountString' variable to manipulate the current count when the vote button is clicked.  Do I have to retrieve the data from the database again for the cell, or is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class TrackTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var voteButtonOn = false

@IBOutlet weak var songTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var votes: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var voteButtonLabel: UIButton!

@IBAction func voteButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if voteButtonOn == false {

        //voteCountString = voteCountString + 1
        //self.votes.text = "\(voteCountString)"


        voteButtonOn = true

    } else if voteButtonOn == true {

        //voteCountString = voteCountString - 1
        //self.votes.text = "\(voteCountString)"

        voteButtonOn = false

    }

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to your parrent `TableViewController` with delegate mechanism.

First create `protocol` for your `vote` action:

```
 protocol VoteProtocol {
        func voteButtonTurnOnFromCellRow(row: Int)
        func voteButtonTurnOffFromCellRow(row: Int)
    }
```

Then make your `TableViewController` class confirm this protocol:

```
class MusicPlaylistTableViewController: UITableViewController, VoteProtocol {
    ...
    func voteButtonTurnOnFromCellRow(row: Int) {
        // Here you have access to your data
        ...
    }
    func voteButtonTurnOffFromCellRow(row: Int) {
        // Here you have access to your data
        ...
        // Also you can update your cell if it needed
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    ...
}
```

Add to your `TrackTableViewCell` delegate object with type of `protocol` and `row` variable:

```
var delegate: VoteProtocol?
var rowValue: Int?
```

Set delegate and row at your `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`:

```
cell.delegate = self
cell.rowValue = indexPath.row
```

Call protocol method in your `voteButton` action:

```
@IBAction func voteButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if voteButtonOn == false {
        if delegate != nil && rowValue != nil {
            voteButtonOn = true
            delegate!.voteButtonTurnOnFromCellRow(rowValue)
        } else {
            // Some Error
        }
    } else if voteButtonOn == true {
        if delegate != nil && rowValue != nil {
            voteButtonOn = false
            delegate!.voteButtonTurnOffFromCellRow(rowValue)
        } else {
            // Some Error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you, this is really helpful.  One clarification - where you added "// Here make voteCountString = voteCountString + 1 or something else you need", I cannot access the voteCountString from within this function.  Do I simply add "row = row + 1"?

Comment: @SB2015 I mean that at this point you need to change your data model `voters` maybe like `voters[row].append(newVoter)` or somthing like this. I just do not quite understand what should be contained in `voters` and wrote the abstract. The main thing is that at this method you get access to the data of your `TableViewController` and you know what concrete cell was carried out the action, and after that you've got the data as you need.